# Read javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Hi I'm working with Kendo and trying to read the data parsed from Json.

Here is my Json result (javascript object)

```
{
"Success":true,"Model":

[{"Attributes":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"CssStyle":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"Value":null}},"Enabled":true,"Selected":false,"Text":"Sunday","Value":"1"},

{"Attributes":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"CssStyle":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"Value":null}},"Enabled":true,"Selected":false,"Text":"Monday","Value":"2"},

{"Attributes":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"CssStyle":{"Keys":[],"Count":0,"Value":null}},"Enabled":true,"Selected":false,"Text":"TuesDay","Value":"3"}]}
```

Now what I want is to list out Text and Value from the above object. 
Either javascript or jquery either way is fine. By using any loop can we get those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(jsonObj.Model,function(){
   console.log(this.Text + " - " + this.Value)
});
```

Demo `----->`  http://jsfiddle.net/GU6g8/

Comment: @jestges  You will see result on console (`F12`).

Comment: @jestges see this to see result on page itself `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/GU6g8/1/